# Linear Transformation of Poisson Point Process

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we have a random variable that follows a Poisson Point Process: $ X \sim poisson(\lambda t) $ and a function $f(x) = ax + b $ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

What is the pdf of $Y = aX + b$?

I know for continuous random variables if $f(x)$ is strictly increasing:
$$f_y(Y = y) = \frac{1}{|a|} f_x\left(\frac{y-b}{a}\right)$$
However I am having trouble doing this for the discrete case. My attempt is as follows suppose for simplicity $t = 1$, thus $X \sim poisson(\lambda)$, Now we have:

\begin{align*}
P(Y \leq y)  &= P(aX + b \leq y)\\
&= P\left(X \leq \frac{y - b}{a}\right)\\
&= F_x\left(\frac{y-b}{a}\right)\\ \\
P(Y = k) &= P(Y \leq k) - P(Y \leq k - 1)\\
&=F_y(Y = k) - F_y(Y =  k - 1)\\
&= F_x(\frac{k-b}{a}) - F_x(\frac{k-1-b}{a}) \\
&= \sum_{n = 0}^{\frac{k-b}{a}} e^{\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} - \sum_{n = 0}^{\frac{k-1 -b}{a}} e^{\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}
\end{align*}

At this point I am stuck because clearly the factorials could take noninteger values, so this difference seems to be meaningless. Can anyone give me a hint as to how to continue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

continue from your last line that $\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{k-b}{a}} e^{\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} - \sum_{n=0}^{\frac{k-b-1}{a}} e^{\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}$ = $e^{\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{\frac{k-b}{a}}}{\frac{k-b}{a}!}$

Since k is an integer calculated from k = aq + b (for some q satisfying X-distribution)

Answer (score 1):

According to your linear transformation model $\Delta y = a \Delta x$ where $\Delta x = 1$. Therefore, $P(Y=k)$ is written as

$$
  P(Y=k)  = P(Y \leq k) - P(Y \leq k - a), 
$$
$$           
     \hspace{0.75in}  = F_x(\dfrac{k-b}{a}) - F_x(\dfrac{k-b-a}{a}),
$$ 
$$
     \hspace{0.75in}  = F_x(\dfrac{k-b}{a}) - F_x(\dfrac{k-b}{a}-1), 
$$
Thus, we get
$$
     P(Y=k) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\frac{k-b}{a}}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!} - 
              \sum_{n = 0}^{\frac{k-b}{a}-1} e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!},
$$
$$
     \hspace{-0.35in} =  e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{{\frac{k-b}{a}}}}{{(\frac{k-b}{a}})!}.
$$